# How to configure microk8s kubernetes to use private container's in https://hub.docker.com/?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, containerd

[microk8s document "Working with a private registry"](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private) leaves me unsure what to do. The **Secure registry** portion says **Kubernetes** does it one way (no indicating whether or not Kubernetes' way applies to microk8), and **microk8s** uses **containerd** inside its implementation.

My YAML file contains a reference to a private container on dockerhub.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blaw
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blaw
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blaw
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: johngrabner/py_blaw_service:v0.3.10
          name: py-transcribe-service
```

When I **microk8s kubectl apply** this file and do a **microk8s kubectl describe**, I get:

```
Warning  Failed     16m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "johngrabner/py_blaw_service:v0.3.10": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/johngrabner/py_blaw_service:v0.3.10": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/johngrabner/py_blaw_service:v0.3.10": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I have verified that I can download this repo from a console doing a docker pull command.

Pods using public containers work fine in microk8s.

The file **/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml** already contains something to make dockerhub work since public containers work. Within this file, I found

```
  # 'plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry' contains config related to the registry
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]

    # 'plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors' are namespace to mirror mapping for all namespaces.
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
        endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io", ]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."localhost:32000"]
        endpoint = ["http://localhost:32000"]
```

The above does not appear related to authentication.

On the internet, I found instructions to create a secret to store credentials, but this does not work either.

```
microk8s kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/home/john/.docker/config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have created the secret you have to then setup your deployment/pod to use that secret in order to download the image. This can be achieved with  `imagePullSecrets` as described on the microk8s document you mentioned.

Since you already created your secret you just have reference it in your deployment:

```yaml
...
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: johngrabner/py_blaw_service:v0.3.10
          name: py-transcribe-service
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
...
```

For more reading check how to [Pull an Image from a Private Registry.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!